# Version control and test-driven development

Tags: unit-testing, version-control, tdd

The standard process for test-driven development seems to be to add a test, see it fail, write production code, see the test pass, refactor, and check it all into source control.

Is there anything that allows you to check out revision x of the test code, and revision x-1 of the production code, and see that the tests you've written in revision x fail? (I'd be interested in any language and source control system, but I use ruby and git)

There may be circumstances where you might add tests that already pass, but they'd be more verification than development.

Comment: I don't think anyone would forbid you to do anything, it's only methodology. I would say that mostly it is very informal even when you define the process developers would run tests out of order (we like to make sure our code works).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. After refactoring the test, you run the test again
2. Then, you refactor the code, then run the test again
3. Then, you don't have to check in right away, but you *could*

In TDD, there is no purpose in adding a test that passes. It's a waste of time. I've been tempted to do this in order to increase code coverage, but that code should have been covered by tests which actually failed first.

If the test doesn't fail first, then you don't know if the code you then add fixes the problem, and you don't know if the test actually tests anything. It's no longer a *test* - it's just some code that may or may not *test* anything.

Comment: With regards to 1, When do you refactor the test? Before or after writing the production code? If afterwards, do you break the production code to make sure the test still works?

One reason why I tend to check in sooner rather than later is to make commits as small and simple as possible.

What approach do you take with untested code? Wait until a bug report comes along? One approach I'm trying is seeing if the new unit test makes the system do better in mutation testing.

Comment: @Andrew: It's not "production code"; it's the code necessary to make the test pass. You refactor only after the test has passed. After the test passes, refactor the test, then run it again. After it passes again, refactor the code and run the tests again. There is never any untested code with TDD. Code is only written to make a failing test pass, and you run all affected unit tests after touching code or test. If in doubt which tests to run, run them all.

Comment: Although I agree that preferably a test should fail first, sometimes you have to ensure that your code covers an edge case, and it would be hard and time consuming to write code that covered the main cases, but failed only on the edge case. Generally at that point you can be confident enough about the way to write tests on the functionality that the failure isn't strictly necessary to have confidence that the test is worth while.

Comment: @John how do you ensure that when you refactor the test code, that you haven't accidentally changed it such that it'll always pass?

Comment: @Yishai: Sorry, I disagree. If the test for your edge case never fails, then it proves nothing by succeeding. In the context of code coverage, you're not just looking for a number - you want the code to be covered by tests that prove that the code is correct. At the extreme, you can imagine you could have 100% coverage by tests that prove nothing. How would that help?

Comment: @Andrew: ReFactoring makes very small changes which do not change the semantics of the code. I don't mean rewriting the test, I mean Refactoring, as the term is used by Fowler, Beck, et.al. in "Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code". These are changes which cannot change the semantics of the test.

Comment: @John: Adding a passing test does have value, it is a covering test.  This might precede refactoring, particularly of legacy code.  Refer to Flowers book on Working Effectively with Legacy Code.  Providing additional tests that pass, can increase the maintainability of the system as a result: if the tests are properly formulated.  Also I've seem the mechanism of tests be reformulated (eg @Theory in junit) to increase test effectiveness. Tests might be refactored.

Answer (score 1):

Simply keep your tests and code in seperate directories, and then you can check out one version of the tests and another of the code.

That being said, in a multi-developer environment you generally don't want to be checking in code where the tests fail.

I would also question the motivation for doing this? If it is to "enforce" the failing test first, then I would point you to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168191/what-dont-you-like-in-agile-development/168300#168300) from the father of (the promotion of) TDD.

Answer (score 1):

"There may be circumstances where you might add tests that already pass, but they'd be more verification than development."

In TDD you *always* watch a test fail before making it pass so that you know it works.

As you've found, sometimes  you want to explicitly describe behaviour that is covered by code you've already written but when considered from outside the class under test is a separate feature of the class.  In that case the test will pass.

But, still watch the test fail.

Either write the test with an obviously failing assertion and then fix the assertion to make it pass.  Or, temporarily break the code and watch all affected tests fail, including the new one.  And then fix the code to make it work again.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep your production and test code in separate versioning areas (e.g. separate projects/source trees/libraries/etc.), most version control systems allow you to checkout previous versions of code and rebuild them.  In your case, you could checkout the x-1 version of production code, rebuild it, then run your test code against the newly built/deployed production deployable.

One thing that might help would be to tag/label all of your code when you do a release, so that you can easily fetch an entire source tree for a previous version of your code.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything that allows you to
>   check out revision x of the test code,
>   and revision x-1 of the production
>   code, and see that the tests you've
>   written in revision x fail?

I think that you are looking for the keyword *continuous integration*. There are many tools that actually are implemented as post-commit hooks in version control systems (aka something that runs on servers/central repository after each commit): for example, they will run your unit tests after each commits, and email the committers if a revision introduces a regression.

Such tools are perfectly able to detect which tests are *new* and never passed from *old* tests that used to pass and that currently fail due to a recent commit, which means that using TDD and continuous integration altogether is just fine: you will probably be able to configure your tools not to scream when a new failing test is introduced, and to complain only on regressions.

As always, I'll direct you to Wikipedia for a [generic introduction on the topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_Integration). And a more detailed, quite famous resource would be the article from [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you `git commit` after writing your failing tests, and then again when they are passing, you should at a later time be able to create a branch at the point where the tests fail.

You can then add more tests, verify that they also fail, `git commit`, `git merge` and then run the tests with the current code base to see if the work you already did will cause the test to pass or if you now need to do some more work.